# How to include figures and images in body text

Tags: style, technical-writing, scientific-publishing

I am writing a text (following MHRA style if that makes a difference) that refers to several images throughout, but I am unsure how to include them in my body text in terms of writing style.

Does it have to be written as 'In figure 3 we can see that ...' or does it just sit in brackets (see figure 3) while the sentence reads more normal? Or can it be both, depending on sentence flow?

I have styles for the actual referencing and inclusion of the visuals, but couldn't find any guidance on how to put them in the actual sentences.

Comment: (Forgot to mention that the images have to sit at the end of the document for this task, so won't be near their mention within the text)

Answer (score 1):

Subsection 1.3.11 of the [MHRA guide](http://www.mhra.org.uk/pdf/MHRA-Style-Guide-3rd-Edn.pdf) specifies:

> The  style  for  referencing  an  illustration  within  the  text  should  be  ascertained from the editor or guidelines for authors but is generally by insertion of the phrase ‘Figure [...]’. A reference is necessary because an illustration is unlikely to follow the relevant text immediately, for technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from a technical writing standpoint (since I have little experience with scientific writing), I think that including the reference in parenthesis (see Figure 3) would be your best bet, something similar to an end note reference.

Conversely, if the images were in close proximity to the relevant text, then something like "As in Figure 3 below," would be more appropriate.